# Dynamic LINQ - Struggling with GROUP BY / SELECT Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have a repeating set of data that I'm retrieving from multiple SQL tables (long story but they all have different names despite having the same data) into a .NET DataTable:-

```
Point_Date  ->  Point_Value0  ->  Point_Value1  ->  Point_Value2  ->  Point_ValueX  
24/11/2014 16:18:07  ->  15.1  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:19:07  ->  15.2  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:20:07  ->  15.3  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:18:07  ->  NULL  ->  16.1  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:19:07  ->  NULL  ->  16.2  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:20:07  ->  NULL  ->  16.3  ->  NULL  
24/11/2014 16:18:07  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  ->  17.1  
24/11/2014 16:19:07  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  ->  17.2  
24/11/2014 16:20:07  ->  NULL  ->  NULL  ->  17.3
```

I want to group the data on the date/time field using LINQ so that I end up with records like:-

24/11/2014 16:18:07  ->   15.1   ->    16.1   ->   17.1

My problem is that I don't know how many sets of data there will be (there are three in the example but there could be any number) so I need to use dynamic LINQ.

I'm ok for the LINQ query for a fixed number of fields:-

```
var dtReport = (from row in dtPoints.AsEnumerable()
                group row by row.Field<DateTime>("Point_Date")
                        into t
                        select new
                        {
                        TempDate = t.Key,
                        Value1 = (double?) t.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Point_Value0") ?? 0),
                        Value2 = (double?)t.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Point_Value1") ?? 0),
                        Value3 = (double?)t.Sum(r => r.Field<double?>("Point_Value2") ?? 0)
                        });
```

But I'm having a real struggle making it dynamic using System.Linq.Dynamic, the following gives me an error:-

```
        var myRpt2 = dtPoints.AsEnumerable()
            .AsQueryable()
            .GroupBy("new ( it[\"Point_Date\"] as GrpByCol1)", "it")
            .Select("new (it.key as TempDate, it.sum(\"Point_Value0\") as SumValue)");
```

- the error being:-

System.Linq.Dynamic.ParseException
{"No applicable aggregate method 'sum' exists"}

I just can't figure out how to refer to the 'Point_Value' fields once I've done the GroupBy - there will be multiple 'sum(Point_ValueX)' fields depending on the number of sets of data but I can't even get it working for a single field at the moment !

Many Thanks,

David.

Comment: Watch videos on LINQ on following youtube channel : https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6n9fhu94yhWi8K02Eqxp3Xyh_OmQ0Rp6 . Especially part 18 and 19.......

Comment: Great shout thanks Vishal, much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can get it done that way. It seems that dynamic linq is not equipped to parse an expression containing an indexer.

You can however use a combination of dynamic LINQ and regular LINQ:

```
var myRpt2 = (
        dtPoints.AsEnumerable()
        .AsQueryable()
        .GroupBy("new ( it[\"Point_Date\"] as GrpByCol1)", "it")
        as IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,DataRow>>
    )
    .Select (r => new { ((dynamic)r.Key).GrpByCol1, 
                        Sum = r.Sum(x => x.Field<decimal>("Point_Value0"))});
```

The main twist is the cast of the `GroupBy` result to `IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,DataRow>>`.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I wouldn't have known about that cast on the GroupBy. What I still can't see is how I'd handle multiple sets of data in the select clause e.g. where I have Point_Value0 through to Point_Value9 ... I was expecting to have to build up a string and use it as a parameter to the Select clause ... is there any way of doing this dynamically ?

Comment: That's going to be hard. You'd have to build a type at runtime, because the number of properties in the anonymous type is not known at compile time. Maybe with some effort you could use an `ExpandoObject`, but I don't see a quick/elegant way to do that.

Comment: Thanks again Gert, for now I've resorted to using dynamic SQL which I'm more comfortable with (using UNIONs and dynamic select / group statement) but your advice will be useful in the future when I'm more comfortable with LINQ in general. Cheers :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62573553/no-applicable-method-select-exists-in-type-datarow

I think my question also have some link with this. can you pls help me. I have tried your solution but its saying no select method exist on IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,DataRow>>