# No applicable method 'Select' exists in type 'DataRow'

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, dynamic-linq, dynamic-linq-core

I have a data table result and I converted it to Enumerable using AsEnumerable extension.

`var dataTableToEnumerable = dataTable.AsEnumerable();`

Now Im doing a groupBy on it using Linq Dynamic Extensions and it works fine but I cant process `Select()`,`Sum()`,`Min()` etc on the aggregrated result.

But methods like Count(),First(),FirstOrDefault() exist.

```
dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null&&it[\"price\"] != null)")
.GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)", "it").Select("it.Sum(\"price\")").
```

Also with reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110445/dynamic-linq-struggling-with-group-by-select-syntax) question I changed my query to this:-

```
(dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null&&it[\"price\"] != null)")
.GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)", "it") as IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,DataRow>>).Select("it.Sum(\"price\")").
```

But Now its showing `No Method Select exist on IEnumerable<IGrouping<DynamicClass,DataRow>>`

Its giving the error `No applicable method 'Select' exists in type 'DataRow'`,
Can Any one help on this?

**#Update1**

I have tried with that first Answer. It's working fine, but how can i change it there is multiple field selection after groupby?
this was my query : -
`dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null && it[\"price\"] != null)") .GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)", "it") .Select("new(it.Select(it[\"price\"] as price,it[\"cost\"] as cost)")`

The result set is correct but,
`.AsEnumerable() .Select(pg => (((IEnumerable<object>)pg).Sum(p => (double)p)));`

this is causing error

> Unable to cast object of type '<>f__AnonymousType15`2[System.Object,System.Object]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: What is `dynamicFilterString` and `dynamicDuplicateRemover`?

Comment: thats a simple string dynamically buils using condiitons, its all working fine

Comment: Could you provide example of these dynamically build string conditions?

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: The standard LINQ `Select` takes a function, not a string. You may have custom extension methods that are supposed to provide this functionality, but we wouldn't know about those. The actual error seems to indicate the `GroupBy` extension method (whatever it is) returns something that is not an `IEnumerable`, so that might be miswritten.

Comment: Yes, Iam using dynamic linq extensions,

Comment: but i cant understand why then methods like Count(),First(),FirstOrDefault() exist successfully.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27110445/dynamic-linq-struggling-with-group-by-select-syntax

I think this question have some link with this. but when i did that solution its saying Select doesnt exist on IEnumerable

Comment: Show *all* code, also including these last efforts. We can't help you without it.

Comment: updated latest changes

Comment: @AmeerPappay the error says you tried to call `Select` on a  single `DataRow` instead of a table or an Enumerable. `Count()` or `Where()` would fail in the exact same way if you tried that, eg `var row=new DataRow(); var x=row.Count();`

Comment: LINQ doesn't work with string arguments either, which means all this code should fail to compile. You can't just write `Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null&&it[\"price\"] != null)")`. Are you using some kind of dynamic LINQ library?

Comment: I have tried count like same as Sum
Select("it.Count()") , but its working fine

Comment: @AmeerPappay none of the code you posted would work with LINQ and DataTable. `Select("it.Count()")` won't compile. You're using some other library. Which one?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Iam using Dynamic Linq and All my dataset is working fine upto beofre last Select Query. That last Select is causing me error

Comment: *Which library*? There's no "Dynamic Linq" in the BCL. In any case, the error is clear - you ended up calling `Select()` on a `DataRow` instead of an `IEnumerable<DataRow>`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos using System.Linq.Dynamic.Core;
https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core

Comment: There's no such library in the BCL. That's not a Microsoft LINQ package, that's a third party package, probably [this one](https://dynamic-linq.net).

Comment: Yes, i have posted github repo above

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Is there any other way to execute dynamic linq queries other than using this lib?

Comment: @AmeerPappay update your question to make it clear this isn't about LINQ, it's about that third-party library. Otherwise people won't understand what you're asking. The GitHub link you posted is a *clone* of the actual library which may contain bugs that were fixed in the original. Post the *full exception* too , not just the description. The error may be caused by a bug deep inside the library, not the actual call to `Select`. The exception's call stack will show which calls led to that error and which was the root operator

Comment: @AmeerPappay lots of ways depending on what you want. LINQ itself is dynamic, you can write `query = query.Where(...)` to add an extra operation to a query. In the question's code the expressions are hard-coded though - those strings don't use any external input

Comment: I can't reproduce your error messages, but I suggest your order your code and methods better in your question. In any case, `"it.Sum(\"price\")"` will never work because `Sum` doesn't take a `string` parameter, and you also can't do `Field<T>` as it is not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract the `price` column using the `DataRow` string indexer method as an `object` and then convert from Dynamic LINQ to LINQ to Objects using `AsEnumerable`, which gets you `IEnumerable<object>` which you can then cast to the appropriate type:

```
var ans = dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null && it[\"price\"] != null)")
            .GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)", "it")
            .Select("it.Select(it[\"price\"])")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(pg => (((IEnumerable<object>)pg).Sum(p => (double)p)));
```

If you don't need any other fields from the `GroupBy`, you can just group the `price` column:

```
var ans = dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null && it[\"price\"] != null)")
            .GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)", "it[\"price\"]")
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(pg => (((IEnumerable<object>)pg).Sum(p => (double)p)));
```

To handle more than one column, you must manually call the extension method `Sum` because extension methods don't work with `dynamic` objects, and you must manually cast the lambdas to `Func` since the compiler can't tell if you need an expression tree or function in a `dynamic` expression:

```
var ans = dataTableToEnumerable.AsQueryable().Where("(it[\"yoko\"] != null && it[\"price\"] != null)")
            .GroupBy("new(it[\"proposalid\"] as proposalid,it[\"yoko\"] as yoko)")
            .Select("it.Select(new(it[\"price\"] as price, it[\"cost\"] as cost))")
            //.AsEnumerable()
            //.Select(pg => (((IEnumerable<object>)pg).Sum(p => (double)p)))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(x => new {
                sumPrice = Enumerable.Sum(x, (Func<dynamic, double>)(y => y.price)),
                sumCost = Enumerable.Sum(x, (Func<dynamic, double>)(y => y.cost))
            })
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Its working fine on singe field,but error on selecting multiple fields, can u pls have a look on question #update1

Comment: @AmeerPappay Once you decide to use `new` inside of Dynamic LINQ, you have create a runtime only type and can no longer use static compile time casting or typing.

Comment: PS Your update #1 has an error, you are missing a `)` and you have either `new` in the wrong place or `Select` missing.